# Simplify vector calculus based on component splitting

Tags: complex, assumptions, vector-calculus

I am interested in verifying a few Vector Calculus expressions using Mathematica.
These expressions are based on splitting a vector field into its transverse components (in the xy- plane) and longitudinal components (z plane).

I've attempted to do something along the lines of

```
$Assumptions = \[Mu] \[Element] 
    Matrices[{3, 3}, Complexes, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]  && 
   Et[x, y] \[Element] Vectors[3] && ( 
    Et[x, y] := {Ex[x, y], Ey[x, y], 0});
```

or

```
$Assumptions = \[Mu] \[Element] 
    Matrices[{3, 3}, Complexes, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]  && 
   Et[x, y] \[Element] Vectors[3] && ( 
   -> Et[x,y]);
```

But I couldn't get Mathematica to simplify

```
FullSimplify[{Ex[x, y], Ey[x, y], 0}]
```

to `Et[x,y]`.

Should it be helpful, the whole expression I am trying to simplify is

```
{0,0,1}\[Cross]\[Mu]Curl[{Ex[x,y],Ey[x,y],Ez[x,y]}E^(\[Gamma] z),{x,y,z}]
```

,where `\[Mu]` is a complex diagonal 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Include the full definitions (values) of any symbol that has one in your code.